# Squid upgrade HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: ssl

I want to use [Squid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29) to upgrade HTTP request to HTTPS using my own certificate, in order to make clients handshake with a server (a reverse proxy) that requires mutual authentication.

How can I configure that in Squid?

Answer (score 0):

SSL bumping is not for adding a client certificate, but is for SSL interception (man-in-the-middle, both sides SSL).

Comment: So what can I use for adding a client certificate. Iam new to squid.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with squid and I don't know of any other software for this.

Comment: Not even with cache_peer? I though it can be done according to this : 
http://squid-web-proxy-cache.1019090.n4.nabble.com/Reverse-proxy-with-mutual-authentication-two-way-ssl-using-squid3-td3693945.html